# Mapbox crashes when using enablingDataOnMapView in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, mapbox, gpx

I am currently trying to load in some GPX trails that I have added as data layers to my Mapbox projects. I can't seem to find any tutorials on how to do this, and the documentation is quite minimal but I think I'm on the right lines. When setting up my RMMapBoxSource I use:

```
normalTileSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:[JSONDict objectForKey:@"normalJSON"] enablingDataOnMapView:rmMapView]
```

However, this code seems to cause a crash which I have narrowed down to this function within RMMapBoxSource:

```
- (id)initWithTileJSON:(NSString *)tileJSON enablingDataOnMapView:(RMMapView *)mapView
```

The crash seems to happen after this line:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = {
                                    .longitude = [[[[feature objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"coordinates"] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue],
                                    .latitude  = [[[[feature objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"coordinates"] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]
                                };
```

This happens because the .longitude arguments are expecting a single float value to be present at each dictionary / array entry, however, as this is line data the geometry actually contains an array of arrays (see below)

```
(lldb) po feature
{
    geometry =     {
        coordinates =         (
                        (
                "-1.577036955712112",
                "53.45438397279663"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577283932066187",
                "53.45452595243928"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577495911943196",
                "53.45465193448263"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577663895584496",
                "53.45474192140945"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577814879253818",
                "53.45478391422645"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578035853910355",
                "53.45481090776157"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578230831430296",
                "53.45483190238889"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578433809749077",
                "53.45489489196479"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578601791632815",
                "53.45494288382392"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578769774353241",
                "53.45501087333442"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578867764622101",
                "53.45505886623693"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578991751525391",
                "53.45510085945654"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579159734454841",
                "53.45517384837989"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579344714762086",
                "53.45523283869398"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579433706945633",
                "53.45530082938201"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579574692230681",
                "53.45535282117395"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579813666487409",
                "53.45542180950893"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579981649876705",
                "53.45550579714063"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.58010563765821",
                "53.45556878789422"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.580282620220255",
                "53.45565877468723"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.580308618611717",
                "53.45569477007211"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.580210633196074",
                "53.45576276354715"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.58008665265216",
                "53.45587275247748"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579970672195915",
                "53.45600773835274"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579872689625363",
                "53.4561437238423"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579810700106625",
                "53.45621671619365"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579730713622791",
                "53.45631070634716"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579658725511261",
                "53.4563886982604"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57964073160034",
                "53.45648268748985"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579658732498264",
                "53.45655567864888"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579711729245241",
                "53.45662966916878"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579746726558638",
                "53.4566656644195"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579763728036581",
                "53.45674965430162"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579745735004357",
                "53.45686464106492"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579718741544114",
                "53.45694363219"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579691749129889",
                "53.45704762037921"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579664755878907",
                "53.45713161091711"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579637762586115",
                "53.45721460157243"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579610769335193",
                "53.45729859211032"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579583775833256",
                "53.45737658335283"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579574778250328",
                "53.45740857972906"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57944279251529",
                "53.45737158604157"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579318805821851",
                "53.45733459223485"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.579185819955492",
                "53.45729159926692"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.5790708315562",
                "53.45723960708761"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578973841628192",
                "53.45720261287849"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578805859326921",
                "53.45714462219381"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578663874371194",
                "53.4570976298298"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57859288153765",
                "53.45706563464601"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57850489032217",
                "53.45702364088996"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578415899226463",
                "53.4569816471488"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578327908220158",
                "53.45694465280559"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.5782399167954",
                "53.45689765963672"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578168923292281",
                "53.45684966633191"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.578053935101909",
                "53.4568026735655"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57797494192944",
                "53.45673968214144"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577920947310341",
                "53.45671368599967"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57781495737225",
                "53.45665069497808"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57771796656521",
                "53.45659270323519"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577629975140295",
                "53.45654571006634"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577540983584083",
                "53.45649271761702"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577417995263894",
                "53.45641972802322"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577320004785753",
                "53.45636673570807"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577250011204483",
                "53.45631974227093"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577161019899239",
                "53.45627274911703"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577020033693308",
                "53.456198759909"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576931043015685",
                "53.4561667649936"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576843051590572",
                "53.45611977182482"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576710065095722",
                "53.45606178061864"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576578079359801",
                "53.45602478693144"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576410097057529",
                "53.45596679624705"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576312107499741",
                "53.45593580134843"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576162123041153",
                "53.45587781039572"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57610012979858",
                "53.45586181319894"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576171119326703",
                "53.45581481765986"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576260106698632",
                "53.45576782185243"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576331096436029",
                "53.45572582572618"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576393087293397",
                "53.45568482961667"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576429081014235",
                "53.45563783459936"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576456075352893",
                "53.455579841008"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576500067906224",
                "53.45552784645858"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576571057016044",
                "53.45547085209385"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576589052223639",
                "53.4554078592238"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576634043569294",
                "53.45532986771276"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576670036829955",
                "53.45527187398721"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576732026599545",
                "53.45520488093097"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576812013501648",
                "53.45512088960277"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576874003689739",
                "53.45506389537222"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57698998782773",
                "53.45501689916236"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577060977356207",
                "53.45496990362333"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577184959029658",
                "53.45488691152183"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577255948558195",
                "53.45483991598281"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577353932216531",
                "53.45472992743959"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577433920039445",
                "53.45466793352791"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577354926866696",
                "53.45460494210376"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577230938875128",
                "53.45453695193758"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577168944293561",
                "53.45448895849854"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577071954155549",
                "53.45444696487665"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577009960285242",
                "53.45441596944129"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576965964007728",
                "53.45437897444217"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576841974886314",
                "53.45428398744669"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576770980336715",
                "53.45421099707764"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576682987823447",
                "53.454138006962"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576585996555583",
                "53.45406901651081"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576533001397909",
                "53.45403302152845"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576197039386156",
                "53.45397903287863"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576073052942334",
                "53.45394803836755"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575905071057671",
                "53.45390004650877"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575772085231569",
                "53.45385805342363"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575639098945156",
                "53.45380506163027"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575551108398205",
                "53.45377906599541"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575436120625117",
                "53.45374207205482"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575294137383311",
                "53.45373607487637"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575188149661912",
                "53.45372607763096"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575064163385244",
                "53.45369908265029"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574922177967459",
                "53.45364109157833"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574807190654529",
                "53.45361509634606"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574674205246593",
                "53.45358310208675"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574542219969917",
                "53.45355710710795"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574462228213454",
                "53.45352511205847"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574170259884024",
                "53.45344612568905"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574002277998752",
                "53.45339813383055"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573922286493275",
                "53.45337213807653"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573807298929057",
                "53.45334014354894"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573683311354813",
                "53.45328215220876"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573568324041621",
                "53.4532561569766"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573444337136871",
                "53.45321416375756"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573338347824944",
                "53.45316617097472"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573161366389684",
                "53.45310318101198"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573064375832265",
                "53.4530511885647"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57296738590255",
                "53.45301419435595"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572887394145797",
                "53.45298219930658"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572746408607524",
                "53.45292420821997"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572640420216095",
                "53.4528982128537"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572542430196818",
                "53.45285621924706"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572498438731395",
                "53.45293421074356"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572453447846136",
                "53.45302320096323"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572408455830956",
                "53.45308519435351"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57236446373787",
                "53.45314818761146"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572293475297391",
                "53.45322118009771"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572221486307108",
                "53.45327817447777"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572141498735468",
                "53.45334616768538"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572017516643486",
                "53.45341916096195"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.5719195321069",
                "53.45350815197193"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571759554285302",
                "53.45358014590279"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57165357049783",
                "53.45366413761924"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571582579420844",
                "53.45367413750369"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571493590081377",
                "53.45367413883087"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571343607588154",
                "53.45366314235942"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571219622441011",
                "53.45366314420856"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571174627580027",
                "53.45365714558421"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571245622800694",
                "53.45374613407407"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571315617722569",
                "53.45382512375315"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571395611446607",
                "53.45390411328312"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571518600438543",
                "53.45399310099754"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571669587834432",
                "53.45412408336232"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571730582076327",
                "53.45416107810773"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571890566426876",
                "53.45424506585759"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.571996555948159",
                "53.45429805805308"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572111543679835",
                "53.4543340521107"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572243529417016",
                "53.45437104579739"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57231452179131",
                "53.4543920422726"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572518498066928",
                "53.45440903723437"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572660481266877",
                "53.45441403452983"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572890453967664",
                "53.45442003039571"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.572979443306876",
                "53.45442002906865"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573165421278124",
                "53.45442602559067"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573306403300404",
                "53.4544000265415"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573475383517212",
                "53.45441102272991"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573643363435276",
                "53.45441202010758"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573776348173533",
                "53.45442801624564"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.573953327431994",
                "53.45443901231481"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57413930494278",
                "53.45443401012879"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574290285767207",
                "53.45440801093068"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574538255893164",
                "53.4544040077029"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574653242117892",
                "53.45440400598835"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574857217263272",
                "53.45439400412123"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.574990200704155",
                "53.45437900389985"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575256168213612",
                "53.45436400169565"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575371153768785",
                "53.4543480018601"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575628122816586",
                "53.45434399849841"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575805100317408",
                "53.45431299950009"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.575974078985746",
                "53.45428700003392"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576116061767002",
                "53.45428199850419"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576364031892828",
                "53.45427799527688"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576585005880464",
                "53.45428899069063"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.576699993192978",
                "53.45431498592306"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.57679798212342",
                "53.45433098258328"
            ),
                        (
                "-1.577027956580985",
                "53.45437897351796"
            )
        );
        type = LineString;
    };
    properties =     {
        description = "";
        id = "marker-hqqqqc9l0";
        stroke = "#1087bf";
        "stroke-opacity" = 1;
        "stroke-width" = 4;
        title = Route2;
    };
    type = Feature;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what function I am meant to be using to draw my GPX / RMPolylineAnnotation data as I can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Try: `.longitude = [[[[[feature objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"coordinates"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:0] floatValue],
.latitude  = [[[[[feature objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"coordinates"] objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:1] floatValue]` to get the i-th "packet" of coordinate.

Comment: As it's a Mapbox function I wasn't sure if I'm allowed to change it, I presumed they would have some functions to deal with RMPolylineAnnotation's too.

Answer (score 1):

The `-enablingDataOnMapView:` argument has to do with Mapbox server-side markers being fetched and auto-added to the map based on edits you've done in the Mapbox online editor. It's not useful for your own custom data.

Also, the `mapID` argument is a Mapbox map ID, not JSON.

Have a look at the docs here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/api/

Comment: I am looking through the docs but the information I can't seem to piece together in my head is how to access the co-ordinates in xcode of the RMPolylineAnnotation (GPX Data) that I've setup online. Obviously in my post above I can see it's present in '[[[feature objectForKey:@"geometry"] objectForKey:@"coordinates"]' but are there any helper functions to access / draw this data?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Okay I've figured out how to write a function to grab the data that I need, just building off the - (id)initWithTileJSON:(NSString *)tileJSON enablingDataOnMapView:(RMMapView *)mapView code. Thanks for the help.